# How to remove tags from sceditor textarea result

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I m using sceditor in website if i add some text into and change styles and save into database. it storing with sceditor tags like,

```
[u][i][b]Hello[/b][/i][/u]
```

How to remove this tags using php or javascript or jquery.

Comment: But if you remove these tags it will have no styling when you retrieve it from the database

Comment: for that what should i do @Ohgodwhy

Comment: you can try `strip_tags ()` function in PHP to remove tags from string

Comment: I already used but its not removing

Comment: I would, instead, convert that to HTML tags so you can still retain your styles if you don't need the BBcode. [Here's a parser](http://www.samclarke.com/2011/09/sbbcodeparser-php-bbcode-parser-class/) to do just such a thing.

Comment: `strip_tags` removes HTML tags, but what you have here, is BB code. If you want to use `strip_tags`, then you do need to turn it in html and then remove the formatting.

Comment: @SaravananMP Please see my function in Answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just Try with this.

```
<?php
function stripSquareTags($text) {
 $pattern = '|[[\/\!]*?[^\[\]]*?]|si';
 $replace = '';
 return preg_replace($pattern, $replace, $text);
}

echo stripSquareTags($text);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP has it's own function for bbcodes - http://php.net/manual/bg/function.bbcode-create.php